# Como usar ""QuickContactBadge" passando um número para o métdo "assignContactFromPhone" por parâmetro?

Tags: android, parâmetros

Gente, estava praticando um pouquinho aqui (sou iniciante) e me deparei com o seguinte problema: Quando eu tento usar uma "QuickContactBadge" passando um número por parâmetro para o método "assignContactFromPhone", a "QuickContactBadge" não funciona. Eu tentei dessa maneira:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText phoneField = findViewById(R.id.phoneField);
        String number = phoneField.getText().toString();

        QuickContactBadge quickContactBadge = findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
        quickContactBadge.assignContactFromPhone(number, true);
    }
}
```

Quando eu passo o número diretamente para o método, funciona normalmente:

```
QuickContactBadge quickContactBadge = findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
    quickContactBadge.assignContactFromPhone("888888888", true);
```

Alguma ideia do motivo e como solucionar o problema?

Comment: O Editext `phoneField` tem algum valor atribuído?

Comment: Sim sim, queria inserir o número por ele e ao clicar na "Badge" poder salvá-lo nos contatos. Quando clico nela, no entanto, parece que o método não é acionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque no momento em que você chama o `assignContactFromPhone()`, o EditText ainda se encontra vazio. Adicione um botão no seu ficheiro activity_main.xml. Assim você clicará nele para chamar o `assignContactFromPhone()` (mas desta vez a chamada acontece depois de ter preenchido o EditText).

E o `onCreate` da sua MainActivity ficará assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText phoneField = findViewById(R.id.phoneField);

    QuickContactBadge quickContactBadge = findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);

    Button botao = findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number = phoneField.getText().toString();
            quickContactBadge.assignContactFromPhone(number, true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Valeu pela ajuda!